# Проблема с задачей C

Tags: c, if

У меня есть система в которую нужно подставить инпут.Каким образом можно реализовать
данную без использования логических операций(Только if/else if/else)?

Мой код для первого примера:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <math.h>
  

void main(){ 

    float x;
    scanf("%f",&x);
    
    if (x <= 0){
        printf("%f",pow(x,3)-8);
    }
        else if (x >= 15){
             printf("%f",pow(x,3)-8);
        }
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: "нужно подставить инпут" - это что значит?!

Comment: @Sergey, функция, зависящая от ввода)))))))

Comment: @ilya484 -"функция, зависящая от ввода" Всё так просто?! Но в приведённом коде я вижу **функцию** *main()*, **зависящую от ввода** *scanf(..)*. Чего не хватает?

Comment: @Sergey, с помощью `if/else` сделать мат.функции с фото

Comment: @Sergey, у него неверное условия

Comment: А что делать при, например, `x == 20`?

Comment: `if(A&&B)C else D` == `if(A){if(B)C else D}else D` ; `if(A||B)C else D` == `if(A)C else{ if(B)C else D}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У Вас  неправильные условия, надо вот так:

```c
if (x >= 0)
   if (x < 15)
       printf("%f",pow(x,3)-8);
```

Без `&&`

Comment: Тогда уж не `if (x >= 0)&&(x < 15){`, а `if ((x >= 0)&&(x < 15)){`...

Comment: @Harry, спасибо

Comment: Приветствую,спасибо за ответ,но каким образом это можно сделать без использования &&?.

Comment: @justdeveloper1, можно)

Comment: @justdeveloper1, если я помог, сделайте пожалуйста мой ответ решением вопроса. Буду очень благодарен

Comment: @ilya484 К сожалентю,у меня выводит ошибку 
Compilation failed due to following error(s).

   12 | if (x >= 0){
      | ^~

Comment: @justdeveloper1, а сейчас ?

Comment: @ilya484 Тоже самое(Ошибка никуда не пропала)

Comment: ну всеее. Никакой галочки=)

Comment: не понял) хзаха